# ArgumentNullException unhandled error when using Linq from local database in C#

Tags: c#, .net, database, linq

I am new to c# and sql database. I got a problem when I request data using LINQ from my local database.

my code is like this:

```
CorporateActionEventType myEventType = (from en in m_db.m_EventTypes
                                           where en.CorporateActionEventType1 == myCorporateActionEvent.EventType
                                           select en).FirstOrDefault();

CAMAIL_PaymentOptions_vw myPaymentOptions = (from po in m_db.m_PaymentOptions
                                           where po.EventID == myCorporateActionEvent.EventID
                                           select po).FirstOrDefault();
```

`CorporateActionEventType`, `CAMAIL_PaymentOptions_vw` is a class I defined to request data from data base. This is LINQ code. I am really not familiar with that.

> ArgumentNullException unhandled error occurred.

Comment: At what line exactly does the exception occur? What is the message of the exception? And also what is the stack trace of the exception looking like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a glance it looks like you may not be instantiating CorporateActionEventType correctly, try using "new".

It may help to post the error message or tell us where exactly you are getting the null exception.

Comment: Yes , that is the problem. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.